# How do I get my my Razer Deathadder drivers back to normal without Synapse?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, razer-mouse

I have Razer Deathadder 3500 dpi, my settings were set to 3rd fastest and enhanced pointer precision. I got the synapse drivers thinking it would help my mouse like 6 months ago. It made my mouse uncontrollable and I uninstalled it/reinstalled it like 8 times, along with removing the mouse drivers. Nothing fixed it, and I factory restored my computer. The mouse is now incredibly fast as it was before, and I need to use 3rd to slowest and enhance pointer precision settings in order to get the settings back to relatively normal.

I tried uninstalling the mouse, everything. When I first got the computer, the mouse worked the way I wanted it to, so I would think that if I factory restored it it would fix the problem (which was not the case).

System details: Windows 7 64 bit alienware x51 etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you want to revert to the old/legacy drivers before Synapse, correct? If so, go to Razer's mice support page here:

http://drivers.razersupport.com//index.php?_m=downloads&_a=view&parentcategoryid=168&nav=0%2C76

Select your mouse, either the regular 3.5G or 3.5G Black Edition, then click on STANDALONE LEGACY DRIVERS, and then look for the third link down that says "WINDOWS LEGACY DRIVER".

If you're a gamer, especially FPS, I suggest you set your Mouse Sensitivity slider to 6/11 in Control Panel, and turn OFF Enhance Pointer Precision, which is sort of like another way of saying "mouse acceleration".

Hope that helps!